# react redux re-render not triggered by state-change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I started learning react and react-redux, but I cant understand how the components or containers know about state changing and to re-render then. I tried a simple Example but cant get it to work the way it should. What I'm trying to do is to have a Counter shown and a button. Every time the button is clicked the counter should increment. Button-click dispatches an action and the state is changed, but somehow the counter is not shown on the screen. Its not even shown the initial State with the 0 counter. I'm also very new to frontend development so maybe it hasnt something to do with redux but with react.

Here is my **index.js**

```
import store from "./store/configureStore"

render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Countercont></Countercont>
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import {combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux'
import counterReducer from "./modules/counter"

const reducer = combineReducers({
    tmp: counterReducer });

const configureStore = createStore(reducer)
export default configureStore;
```

**Mycounter.js**

```
const Mycounter = ({counter, inc}) => (
<div>
    <p>"counter"</p>
    <p>{counter}</p>
    <Button onClick={inc}>Inc</Button>
</div>
)

export default Mycounter
```

**countercont.js** the container component

```
const Countercont = ({counter, inc}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Mycounter counter={counter} inc={inc}/>
        </div>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {counter: state.counter};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {inc: () => dispatch(inc())}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Countercont);
```

**counter.js** the action and reducer

```
export default function reducer(state = {counter: 0}, action) {
    console.log(state) //-> shows the correct state
    switch (action.type) {
        case "c":
            console.log("Inc")
            return {...state, counter: state.counter + 1}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export function inc() {
    return {type: "c"}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your counter state defined inside `counterReducer` which is registered against `tmp` key

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
   tmp: counterReducer
});
```

So in order to get that value your component `mapStateToProps` callback shoudl get this value from whole state using your reducer key which is `tmp` in your code

So it should be like

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {counter: state.tmp.counter};
};
```

instead of

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {counter: state.counter};
};
```

Comment: This comment is correct, "tmp" was declared as key in combineReducers.

Comment: thank you very much. I didnt knew the key was actual important! But it works now!